# Proving Inf with epsilon

Tags: real-analysis

Let X denote a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for each $\epsilon$ > 0,
there exists x in X such that inf X $\leq$ x < inf X + $\epsilon$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2984463.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ \epsilon >0$, then $ \inf X + \epsilon $ is not a lower bound of $X$, hence there is some $x \in X$ such that $ x < \inf X + ϵ.$

Furthermore it is clear that $\inf X ≤ x.$